# How to reuse JSF Beans of SessionScope across HTTP and HTTPS requests?

Tags: http, jsf-2, https

Consider this index.xhtml Page.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">
    <f:view locale="en" encoding="UTF-8">
        <h:head>
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        </h:head>

        <h:body class="ui-grid" id="body">
            <h:form>
                <h:commandButton value="Invalidate Session" action="#{loggedInUser.invalidateSession}"/>
            </h:form>
        </h:body>
    </f:view>
</html>
```

And this SessionScoped bean.

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.enterprise.context.SessionScoped;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.inject.Named;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

@Named
@SessionScoped
public class LoggedInUser implements Serializable {

    String user;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        String remoteUser = this.user = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRemoteUser();
        String sessionId = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSessionId(false);
        System.out.println("Initializing. With SESSION ID " + sessionId);
        System.out.println("Initializing. With remote user " + remoteUser);
    }

    public void invalidateSession() throws ServletException{
        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequest();
        request.logout();
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().invalidateSession();
    }

    public String getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public void setUser(String user) {
        this.user = user;
    }
}
```

I visit the page in two browser windows.
One Window (W1) has the URL https://localhost:8181/pfdialogdemo/index.xhtml
The other Window (W2) has the URL http://localhost:8080/pfdialogdemo/index.xhtml

These are the Steps I do.

1. On W1 click "Invalidate Session".
2. Reload W1.
3. Reload W2.

The output produced by LoggedInUser.init(); is

```
Information:   Initializing. With SESSION ID b6d2858cc441c52540f54ee4cb0c  
Information:   Initializing. With remote user null 
Information:   Initializing. With SESSION ID b6d60472f8d5cca5b6feb5ff32d5 
Information:   Initializing. With remote user null
```

If I do.

1. On W2 click "Invalidate Session".
2. Reload W2.
3. Reload W1.

The output is.

```
Information:   Initializing. With SESSION ID b6de615078648aa44566af533a9f
Information:   Initializing. With remote user null
```

Why is the SessionScoped bean created a second time in the first example? How to make sure, that the SessionScoped bean is not created twice? Why is it created only once in the second example?

This example uses Glassfish 4.1 with JSF 2.2 (Mojarra)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is expected behavior conform [HTTP state (cookie) specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6265) (i.e. beyond control of JSF).

Cookies created during a HTTPS request aren't available to HTTP requests on same domain/path. This would otherwise have been a security leak which destroys the integrity and sense of HTTPS. It's only possible the other way round.

Just disable HTTP on your web application by permanently redirecting from HTTP to HTTPS.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. How would I permanently redirect from HTTP to HTTPS in a JSF application?

Comment: Here's the right question: "How would I permanently redirect from HTTP to HTTPS in GlassFish server?".